# Dynamic table HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, formatting

I need to read an existing table with Javascript and then copy and paste it in a popup.
After that I've done that, I need to dynamically change the table.
The copied table in the popup must have the same rows, but it must have also a fixed height.
The table to copy does not a have a fixed amount of rows.
The popup content must be printed on paper, so I cannot apply a simple overflow to
the table.
I don't want to reduce the font size to insert everything in the fixed space, but I would like to dynamically extend the table width if the readed content is to long.
For example, here is my starting table (6 rows):

```
H1   H2   H3
TD1  TD1 TD1 
TD2  TD2 TD2 
TD3  TD2 TD3 
TD4  TD4 TD4 
TD5  TD5 TD5 
TD6  TD6 TD6
```

The copied table should be something like:

```
H1   H2   H3 H1   H2  H3
TD1  TD1 TD1 TD4  TD4 TD4 
TD2  TD2 TD2 TD5  TD5 TD5 
TD3  TD2 TD3 TD6  TD6 TD6
```

Or

```
H1   H2   H3 
TD1  TD1 TD1 TD4  TD4 TD4 
TD2  TD2 TD2 TD5  TD5 TD5 
TD3  TD2 TD3 TD6  TD6 TD6
```

(I do not care to repeat the headers).

What's the fastest/smartest way to do that?

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140554/jquery-loop-through-table-cells-then-rows-each Essentially, you can iterate through the cells, copy them to an array, and then recreate the table for an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by writing this function

```
var nuova_tabella = popupWin.document.createElement("table");
        nuova_tabella.className = "table table-bordered table-condensed"
        var thead = popupWin.document.createElement("thead");
        nuova_tabella.appendChild(thead);
        var head1 = popupWin.document.createElement("th");
        head1.innerHTML = "Abilita";
        var head2 = popupWin.document.createElement("th");
        head2.innerHTML = "Costo";
        thead.appendChild(head1);
        thead.appendChild(head2);
        var tbody = popupWin.document.createElement("tbody");
        nuova_tabella.appendChild(tbody);
        div_destro.appendChild(nuova_tabella);
        for (var i = 1; i < numero_abilita; i++) {
            if (count >= 10) {
                count = 0;
                var nuova_tabella = popupWin.document.createElement("table");
                nuova_tabella.className = "table table-bordered table-condensed";
                var thead = popupWin.document.createElement("thead");
                nuova_tabella.appendChild(thead);
                var head1 = popupWin.document.createElement("th");
                head1.innerHTML = "Abilita";
                var head2 = popupWin.document.createElement("th");
                head2.innerHTML = "Costo";
                thead.appendChild(head1);
                thead.appendChild(head2);
                tbody = popupWin.document.createElement("tbody");
                nuova_tabella.appendChild(tbody);
                div_destro.appendChild(nuova_tabella);
            }
            tbody.appendChild(abilita.rows[i].cloneNode(true));
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way to do this would be to grab the markup for the table, and insert it into the pop-up, and apply a class or id to restyle it. Perhaps using scroll for the overflow instead of trying to reorder the cells. Or perhaps a different layout that has the headings run down the first column.

jQuery for this might look like::

```
$('#popup').append($('table').html().addClass('popTable'));
```

and the css
    .popTable{overflow:auto;}

With regard to the easiest way to rearrange your table with javascript, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot apply overflow because the content of the popup must be printed on paper.
Also, the table to copy does not a have a fixed amount of rows.
I need a kind of responsive table, i hope that my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/w2n7B/5/

sample usage:

```
var table  = document.getElementById('table');
var tbl    = new jTable(2);
var rTable = tbl.transformTable(table));
document.getElementById('popup').appendChild(rTable);
```

NOTE: th must present in source table

HTML

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2</th>
        <th>h3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 - 1</td>
        <td>1 - 2</td>
        <td>1 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 - 1</td>
        <td>2 - 2</td>
        <td>2 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 - 1</td>
        <td>3 - 2</td>
        <td>3 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 - 1</td>
        <td>4 - 2</td>
        <td>4 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5 - 1</td>
        <td>5 - 2</td>
        <td>5 - 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="copy"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function jTable(maxRows, withHeaders){
    var _maxRows     = 0;
    var _withHeaders = false;

    //maxRows - max rows
    //withHeaders - with header on each column
    var construct = function(maxRows, withHeaders){
        _maxRows     = maxRows;
        _withHeaders = typeof(withHeaders) == 'undefined' ? false : withHeaders;
    }

    //sourceTable - table with data to be converted into limited number of rows table
    this.transformTable = function(sourceTable){
        //create limited rows table(rTable)
        var copyTable = document.createElement('table');
        //store source table headers
        var headers   = sourceTable.rows[0].cells;

        for(var r = 0; r < sourceTable.rows.length - 1; r++){
            //defined index of rTable row
            var index = r - Math.floor(r / _maxRows) * _maxRows;
            var row   = copyTable.rows[index] || copyTable.insertRow(index);

            //copy cells
            for(var c = 0; c < headers.length; c++){
                var cell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
                cell.innerText = sourceTable.rows[r + 1].cells[c].innerText;                
            }
        }

        addHeaders(copyTable, sourceTable.rows[0].cells);
        return copyTable;
    }

    //add headers to rTable
    var addHeaders = function(table, headers){
        var headerRow   = table.insertRow(0);
        var headerCount = _withHeaders ? table.rows[1].cells.length : headers.length;

        for(var h = 0; h < headerCount; h++){
            var th        = document.createElement('th');
            //index of source table header
            var textIndex = h - Math.floor(h / headers.length) * headers.length;

            th.innerText = headers[textIndex].innerText;
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        }
    }

    construct.call(this, maxRows, withHeaders)
}

window.onload = function(){
    var sourceTable = document.getElementById('tbl');
    var tTable = new jTable(2, false);
    document.getElementById('copy').appendChild(tTable.transformTable(sourceTable));
}
```